# Динамические компоненты

Tags: delphi

Такое вот заданице...

Можно ли создать динамический объект/компонент (например, `TImage`), так, чтобы он был внизу всех остальных компонентов.

Т.е. он создаётся поверх всех остальных компонентов. Можно ли это исправить, чтобы он создавался внизу?

И ещё: как очистить (грубо говоря, удалить) динамические компоненты из переменной, если их очень много?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под 
> очистить (грубо говоря, удалить) динамические компоненты" 
?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы разместить компонент позади всех остальных в рамках некоторого контейнера используйте:

```
Image1.SendToBack;
```

Для вытаскивания вперед:

```
Image1.BringToFront;
```

Answer (score 1):

я сейчас работаю с динамикой, так что просто скину пример кода:

```
 var
   LLabelArray         : array of TLabel;
   LEditButtonArray    : array of TButton;
   LDeleteButtonArray  : array of TButton;
   i,z: integer;
   str: TStringList;
   Sender: TObject;
 begin
  // отрисовка динамических объектов
  // обнуляем переменную, отвечающую за позицию объекта
  z:= 0;
  // создаем стринглист
  str:= TStringList.Create;
  // читаем секцию и кидаем ее значени
  MainForm.CalendarIni.ReadSectionValues(DateToStr(MonthCalendar1.Date), str);

  // Если массивы не пустые, то
  if (Length(LLabelArray) <> 0) and (Length(LEditButtonArray) <> 0)
  and (Length(LDeleteButtonArray) <> 0)then
   begin
    // удаляем объекты
    for I := 0 to Length(LLabelArray) -1 do
      begin
        LLabelArray[i].Free;
      end;
    for I := 0 to Length(LEditButtonArray) -1 do
      begin
        LEditButtonArray[i].Free;
      end;
    for I := 0 to Length(LDeleteButtonArray) -1 do
      begin
        LDeleteButtonArray[i].Free;
      end;
    // очищаем массивы
    SetLength(LLabelArray, 0);
    SetLength(LEditButtonArray, 0);
    SetLength(LDeleteButtonArray, 0);
   end;

  // Заполняем массив объектами
  for I := 0 to str.Count -1 do
  // Если строка не пустая, то создаем объект
  if MainForm.CalendarIni.ReadString(Copy(str[i], 1, Pos('=', str[i])-1),  
  'Caption',  '') <> '=' then
  // Если в строке текст, то создаем лэйбл
  if MainForm.CalendarIni.ReadString(Copy(str[i], 1, Pos('=', str[i])-1),
  'Caption', '') <> '-' then
     begin
       // ============= РИСУЕМ КНОПКУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЯ ===========
       // Увеличиваем размер массива на 1
       SetLength(LEditButtonArray, Length(LEditButtonArray) + 1);
       // Создаем объект
       LEditButtonArray[Length(LEditButtonArray) - 1]         := 
       TButton.Create(Owner);
       // настраиваем его свойства
       // устанавливаем родителя
       LEditButtonArray[Length(LEditButtonArray) - 1].Parent  := Panel1;
       // отступ слева
       LEditButtonArray[Length(LEditButtonArray) - 1].Left    := self.Lleft;
       // отступ сверху
       LEditButtonArray[Length(LEditButtonArray) - 1].Top     := 25 * z + self.Ltop;
       // длина и ширина
       LEditButtonArray[Length(LEditButtonArray) - 1].Width   := 25;
       LEditButtonArray[Length(LEditButtonArray) - 1].Height  := 20;
       // вписываем в тэг номер объекта
       LEditButtonArray[Length(LEditButtonArray) - 1].Tag     := z;
       // Обработчик нажатия
       LEditButtonArray[Length(LEditButtonArray) - 1].OnClick := 
       self.EditButtonOnClick;
       // Caption
       LEditButtonArray[Length(LEditButtonArray) - 1].Caption := 'Ред';

       // ============= РИСУЕМ КНОПКУ УДАЛЕНИЯ ===========
       // Увеличиваем размер массива на 1
       SetLength(LDeleteButtonArray, Length(LDeleteButtonArray) + 1);
       // Создаем объект
       LDeleteButtonArray[Length(LDeleteButtonArray) - 1]         := 
       TButton.Create(Owner);
       // настраиваем его свойства
       // устанавливаем родителя
       LDeleteButtonArray[Length(LDeleteButtonArray) - 1].Parent  := Panel1;
       // отступ слева
       LDeleteButtonArray[Length(LDeleteButtonArray) - 1].Left    := self.Lleft + 30;
       // отступ сверху
       LDeleteButtonArray[Length(LDeleteButtonArray) - 1].Top     := 25 * z + 
       self.Ltop;
       // длина и ширина
       LDeleteButtonArray[Length(LDeleteButtonArray) - 1].Width   := 25;
       LDeleteButtonArray[Length(LDeleteButtonArray) - 1].Height  := 20;
       // вписываем в тэг номер объекта
       LDeleteButtonArray[Length(LDeleteButtonArray) - 1].Tag     := z;
       // Caption
       LDeleteButtonArray[Length(LDeleteButtonArray) - 1].Caption := 'Уд';
       // Обработчик нажатия
       LDeleteButtonArray[Length(LDeleteButtonArray) - 1].OnClick := 
       self.DeleteButtonOnClick;

       // ============= РИСУЕМ ЛЭЙБЛЫ ============
       // Увеличиваем размер массива на 1
       SetLength(LLabelArray, Length(LLabelArray) + 1);
       // Создаем объект
       LLabelArray[Length(LLabelArray) - 1]         := TLabel.Create(Owner);
       // настраиваем его свойства
       LLabelArray[Length(LLabelArray) - 1].Parent  := Panel3;
       LLabelArray[Length(LLabelArray) - 1].Left    := self.Lleft + 10;
       LLabelArray[Length(LLabelArray) - 1].Top     := 25 * z + self.Ltop;
       LLabelArray[Length(LLabelArray) - 1].Caption := 
       MainForm.CalendarIni.ReadString(DateToStr(MonthCalendar1.Date), Copy(str[i], 
       1, Pos('=', str[i])-1), '');
       // Увеличиваем z
       inc(z);
    end;
 end;
```

Comment: Подкину мысль: налегайте на `with ... do`, сильно повысит читаемость.

Ну или хотя бы короткие названия переменных на время заполнения пропертей:

       EditButton := TButton.Create(Owner);
       EditButton.Parent  := Panel1;
       EditButton.Left    := self.Lleft;
       EditButton.Top     := 25 * z + self.Ltop;
       EditButton.Width   := 25;
       EditButton.Height  := 20;
       EditButton.Tag     := z;
       EditButton.OnClick := self.EditButtonOnClick;
       EditButton.Caption := 'Ред';
       LEditButtonArray[Length(LEditButtonArray) - 1] := EditButton;

Comment: это первый опыт. развиваемся :)